# Why does the galvanometer read 0 at a certain point?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

We are studying potentiometers in class, and our teacher wasn't able to explain why the galvanometer would read 0 at a certain point along the wire. I think I'm not quite understanding how the current is flowing through the circuit because of the orientation of the cells. Somehow they're supposed to 'cancel each other out' but I'm not sure how this works.

If anyone could explain this I would be very grateful!

Comment: Really? Or was it that you did not understand your teacher's explanation? (If it is the orientation that bothers you, of course, you may rotate the schematic by 90 degrees.)

Comment: @Pieter nope! this question was prefaced by her saying about 10 minutes earlier, 'if I don't understand something, I just ignore it.' After I and other students has asked her to explain multiple times, the best answer we got was that she didn't understand it when she learnt it at school since its a little beyond the syllabus, so we don't need to know.

Comment: That is a horrible attitude for a teacher! And this is not really difficult. Just do not try to compute currents.

Answer (score 1):

The driver cell in the OP's figure is connected to the potentiometer wire AB which is acting as a [voltage divider](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/voldiv.html) with the output at the jockey. It may help to rotate the figure. (It may also help to set the bottom potential to zero, ground.) Then that part of the figure looks like this:
[image]

Now, if the output voltage $V_{\rm out}$ is equal to the unknown emf of cell X, then there won't be a current in the galvanometer.